Confusion in deriving von Karman equation for strip rolling

In the derivation for von Karman equation for metal strip rolling, an infinitesimal element is chosen as shown in the picture above. The equilibrium equation for the element is as follows:
$$\left[\sigma_x+\text{d}\sigma_x\right][h+\text{d}h] - \sigma_x h-2pR \text{d}\theta \sin\theta \pm 2\mu pR \text{d}\theta \cos\theta = 0$$
Upon further simplification and ignoring the product of small quantities, we obtain the von Karman equation:
$$\frac{\text{d}\left(\sigma_x h\right)}{\text{d}\theta} = 2pR(\sin\theta \pm \mu\cos\theta)$$
Notice that the parameters of the element are chosen such that there will be product of $(σ_x+\text{d}σ_x)$ and $(h+\text{d}h)$, i.e. $(σ_x+\text{d}σ_x)$ acting on left face and height of element at left face is also $(h+\text{d}h)$.
My confusion is: When we choose to keep $(σ_x+\text{d}σ_x)$ on the right side face, keeping $(h+\text{d}h)$ on the left face, the resulting equilibrium equation does not give us the von Karman equation. Why does this happen? Shouldn't the final result be independent of the variable chosen? Is there a certain rule for this? Where am I making a mistake?


You should show your derivation and the result. It is possible there is no mistake, but I am not sure if the result will be useful. Final result cannot be independent of chosen variable if that variable is chosen with a different meaning.

The derivation is shown in the question. The first equation is equilibrium of forces acting on the element along X direction (mu is the coefficient of friction and p is the pressure exerted by the roll on the element). Now, opening up the brackets and multiplying gives us the required von Karman equation (the term dσ*dh is neglected).

I really mean your derivation, i.e. the version you are confused about, not the one from the book, which is already in the question.

@Tomáš Létal OK just give me some time...I will upload it soon

@Tomáš Létal Please take a look

@Tomáš Létal Can you please answer this question, if possible? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61066/minimum-number-of-teeth-to-avoid-interference-in-gears

I think you forgot $\text{d}\theta$ on the right side. So your result should be:
$$\frac{\text{d}\sigma_x}{\text{d}\theta} - \frac{\text{d}h}{\text{d}\theta}$$
The broader problem with your approach is in the variables. In your version, $\frac{\text{d}\sigma_x}{\text{d}\theta}$ represents a change when going from left to right, but $\frac{\text{d}h}{\text{d}\theta}$ represents a change when going in the opposite direction. So to compensate for this, you would need to use $\theta^* = -\theta$ and consequently $\frac{\text{d}\sigma_x}{\text{d}\theta^*} = -\frac{\text{d}\sigma_x}{\text{d}\theta}$. This is why all the quantities $q_i$ are defined at some coordinate $x$ and their changed versions $q_i+\text{d}q_i$ are at coordinate $x+\text{d}x$. So you need to pay attention to convention of $\theta$ coordinate in the original figure (on the right), where it goes from right to left and use quantities $h(\theta)$ and $\sigma_x(\theta)$ with this convention in mind.
I moved $\theta$ a bit in the figure, so it is more clear: 

I understand now, Thanks a lot! Yes, I missed the dθ on the right side.
